# iPhone multi view application design question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, application-design, multiview

I have a question about iPhone app design approach... I have in mind to make some complex application and I think that the best base for my needs is "Tab Bar Application" template. Actually, I've been looking some apps on iPhone, and AppStore's design is definitely what I need; a Tab Bar based app with different options on the top - Segmented Control, Search Bar, Navigation Bar etc. Each of Tab Bar's views would have another 'navigation-based app' or 'utility application' inside of it...

I spent lots of time on searching for my 'problem' but I still can't comprehend how to 'nest' few navigation controls in one application... Really, any link or thought would be extremely appreciated! Even your mind flow about how to accomplish what I need is nice because I'm totally tapping in dark here...

Just to mention that I'm pretty much new in Objective-C and I've heard something about Delegations but I don't know exactly how to use that... Is that something that would help me build my idea?

Thank you very very much for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW2) has a section on doing what you're thinking. The link gives a conceptual overview of how the application is laid out and gives code samples on how to do it.